# Solving with L'Hôpital's rule. What is wrong?

Tags: calculus, limits

L'Hôpital's rule can be used infinitely many times as the limit remains $0/0$. However, this problem does not work with L'Hôpital's rule (I may have counted wrong).

Here it is:
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\left(e^x+\sin x\right)x+e^x-\cos x}{x^2}\right)$$
We use L'Hôpital's rule once:
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{2\sin x\left(x\right)+x\left(\cos\left(x\right)+e^x\right)+2e^x}{2x}\right)$$
One more time:
$$\left(\frac{−x\sin\left(x\right)+3\cos\left(x\right)+\left(x+3\right)e^x}{2}\right)$$
This will equal to $3$. But the real answer is $1$:
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\left(e^x+\sin x\right)x+e^x-\cos x}{x^2}\right)=1$$

$3$ is not equal to $1$

Thoughts?

Comment: When doing MathJax, you need to put the maths between dollar signs.

Comment: $6$ is not equal to $1$, but $3$ is also not equal to $6$. So is it $6$ or $3$?

Comment: I don't think you differentiated the first numerator correctly.

Comment: Please check the statement of your limit. Is it correct?

Comment: For me, what you posted tends to $\infty$.

Comment: It looks like you missed a sign.  In the original expression check the second $e^x$ factor in the numerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying L-Hopital once, the expression that you obtain is not of the indeterminate form ( 0/0  or infinity/infinity) , hence you cannot apply l- hopital again.
Now as after applying l hopital you do not get a finite limit, it does not imply that actual limit does not exist, its just that L-Hopital method fails here.

**Important** - If you use l'Hopital rule and find that the limit does not exist you **cannot** conclude that the initial limit does not exist. In that case you must use other methods to analyse the limit.

**Note** - plotting its graph suggests that its limit does not exist at **0** . It shoots towards infinity.
Also note that by using L'Hopital method you cannot conclude the existence of limit. That's why i used this graphical method of analysis.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply l'Hôpital on a non indeterminate form.

Let's see what happens with a Taylor expansion at degree $2$:
\begin{align}
(e^x+\sin x)x+e^x-\cos x
&=(1+x+x+o(x))x+1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-1+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2) \\
&=x+2x^2+x+x^2+o(x^2)\\
&=2x+3x^2+o(x^2)
\end{align}
Thus we see that the given limit cannot be finite (and indeed it is $-\infty$ from the left and $\infty$ from the right).

It's also difficult to understand how the given solution could be $1$, unless we do a sign switch:
\begin{align}
(e^x+\sin x)x-e^x+\cos x
&=(1+x+x+o(x))x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}+1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2) \\
&=x+2x^2-x-x^2+o(x^2)\\
&=x^2+o(x^2)
\end{align}
This proves that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^x+\sin x)x-e^x+\cos x}{x^2}=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can't use L^Hopital's rule since $$\lim _{x\to 0}\left({2\sin x\left(x\right)+x\left(\cos\left(x\right)+e^x\right)+2e^x}\right)=2\ne 0$$Also the limit doesn't exist since it is $\Large{2\over \pm 0}$ .

Comment: No, we cannot conclude if the original limit exists or not, its just that l-hopital method fails to find the limit. See my answer above